# Okhttp in B2B client/server java based services (high concurrency)

Tags: java, multithreading, okhttp

In all examples I see, Okhttp is often used in android stack.

I want to use it in B2B java services to communicate between 2 services via REST.

I have questions about thread-safety and the behaviour of Okhttp in a high-concurrency environment.

Can anyone tell me if Okhttp is more suitable for my case, or I must use another http client library?

Answer (score 1):

In the application I work on, we use it to make thousands of requests per minute without problem. We haven't tested it much higher than that but don't anticipate problems.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the design decisions OkHttp make are great for a client application.  Little things like locks on the connection pool to ensure a single multiplexed connection is established to a backend.

But for a large high throughput server-server use case, it would be more typical to use Netty via Finagle or RxNetty.  In this case the library will be closer to fully asynchronous IO and built with load balancing across multiple connections etc.